# Why the php curl url is redirecting me on it's own from the php file to the url automatically?

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to extract data from a site but when I load the php file so instead I am automatically redirected to the site..!

Here Take a look at the video as :
http://recordit.co/KOwXS5KTKR

**PHP :**

```
$url = "http://extratorrent.cc/view/popular/TV.html?page=1&srt=seeds&pp=50&order=desc";

 $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, FALSE);       

    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

print_r($data);
```

**JUST ASSUMING :**

While taking a look at the site source page code so I saw JavaScript as :

```
<script type="text/javascript">window.functions = new Array();</script>
<script src="https://extra.to/scripts/script.js?2" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I think this may be causing the redirection so if that is correct so then how would I be able to prevent it???

I did some research and I came to the result that `window.location` can't be fully disabled so that the site won't  redirect on it's own...I would want to know If I can ignore to load the following code in HTML in CURL Page loading through PHP?

Answer (score 0):

There is definitely a Javascript that checks your window.location against extratorrent domain names and IPs. Although I cannot find the line that makes the redirect itself, it must be somewhere there.

```
r = 0,
    d = ['.cc', '.com', '.ws','live.com','.is'],
    p = ['195.144.21.16','195.144.21.19','195.144.21.22','88.190.233.44'],
    w = window.location,
[...]
for (i in d) {
    if (w.hostname == e + d[i]) {
        r = 1;
    }
}

for (i in p) {
    if (w.hostname == p[i]) {
        r = 1;
    }
}
```

If you want to extract the data from this site, you should consider if you ever need to output the data by `print_r`. If you process the contents, it won't affect your page until you make the output. You can try:

1. Disabling Javascript in your browser for the development (may or may not work, depending on the website dependence on JS).
2. Stripping scripts from the curl response, even by a simple `str_replace`.
3. Process/parse the contents without outputting it to the browser.